# Reading/Writing XML Files with Spring Integration

Tags: java, xml, file, spring-integration

I'm currently implementing a few import/export mechanisms with Spring Integration and all in all it goes quite well, but there seems to be a gap in the capabilities that I don't understand:

There is [Spring Integration File](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/file.html) for polling directories, writing to files, ... I can use this to poll a directory and get a `Message<File>` for every file I'm interested in.

There is [Spring Integration XML](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/xml.html) for handling `Document` objects, apply XPath, XSLT, ... I can use this to analyze XML documents, enrich headers using XPath, split documents, ...

What I'm missing is the link between the two:

- Given a directory into which XML files will be dropped I want a channel that contains a `Message<Document>` for each file in it
- Given a channel with `Message<Document>` I want a configuration that will write each one into a file.

Marshallers/Unmarshallers *seem* to be exactly what I'm looking for (or at least bring me halfway to a `byte[]`), but they *seem* to only be capable to transforming a `Document` to/from a POJO via some mapping framework.

For parsing I can help myself with this simple class:

```
public class FileToDocumentTransformer extends AbstractFilePayloadTransformer<Document> {
    @Override
    protected Document transformFile(File file) throws Exception {
        return DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(file);
    }
}
```

But I have not found a suitable counterpiece to this *and* I can't believe that Spring Integration doesn't already come with this trivial ability built-in.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

See `DefaultXmlPayloadConverter.convertToDocument`. This converter is used internally in many endpoints (XPath in particular, but others too). It can handle File and String payloads. You can invoke it directly as a transformer too.

See the `transformer` package in the [spring-integration-xml project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-xml) for more info.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm dense, but I still don't get it: do I have to define a bean of that type on my own? I was ideally looking for some simple configuration (maybe with the integration-xml namespace) or a single expression I can use as a service activator.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up writing this class:

```
public class DocumentToBytesTransformer {
    public byte[] transform(Document document) throws Exception {
        Transformer tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        tr.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        tr.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(baos));
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

With this configuration:

```
<int:service-activator method="transform">
    <bean class="package.DocumentToBytesTransformer"/>
</int:service-activator>
```

For me this is in a `<chain>`, otherwise you'd need `input-channel` and `output-channel`, of course.

I'm *pretty sure* that this is not the best possible solution (which is why I asked this in the first place), but it works for me.